# nginx/php-fpm with location exception - 404

Tags: php, nginx, https

I have configured http->https redirection + non-www->www redirection.
I want to exclude two paths, so that they won't be redirected to https.
I have tried many possible configuration, I either get a 404 or I get redirected to the https version.

Here's the current config, which returns a 404, when trying to get a /loc2/ path (#curl http://www.server.dev/loc2/18a9BM4Lay):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name server.dev;
    location / {
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    location /loc1/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    }
    location /loc2/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.server.dev;
    root /var/www/web/server/public;

    location / {
#    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

        location ^~ /loc1/ {
#        root /var/www/web/server/public;
    index index.php;
#        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        include pool_web.conf;
        }

        location ^~ /loc2/ {
#       root /var/www/web/server/public;
    index index.php;
#        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
      location ~ \.php$ {
              # regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
              fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
              # Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
              try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
              # Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
              # see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
              set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
              fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
              include fastcgi.conf;
              fastcgi_read_timeout 360s;
              fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

              fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/server-php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
#   include pool_web.conf;

      }

        }


server {
#    listen 80;
#    listen [::]:80;

    listen 443 ssl http2;

     ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/server.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;

    server_name server.dev;
    rewrite     ^   $scheme://www.server.dev$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
#    listen 80;

    listen 443 ssl http2;

     ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/server.crt;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;

    server_name www.server.dev;

    root /var/www/web/server/public;

    index index.php;

   location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /images/ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include pool_web.conf;
    }

    location ~ \.(css|htc|less|js|js2|js3|js4)$ {
        expires 31536000s;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }

    location ~ \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|woff|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
        expires 31536000s;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a file called `/var/www/web/server/public/loc2/18a9BM4Lay`? Or do you expect something else to happen?

Comment: That file doesn't exist. Rather index.php handles the /loc2/ path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `try_files` statement to define a default handler. The `index` directive only works if a directory is specified.

For example:

```
location ^~ /loc2/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /loc2/index.php;
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: 2. `location ^~ /loc2/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
 ...
 }
`
redirects to https:

#curl http://www.server.dev/loc2/18ayBMOLVy -L -k -I
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.10.1 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 27 Dec 2016 15:43:14 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 194
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://www.server.dev/loc2/18ayBMOLVy

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: 1. `location ^~ /loc2/ { try_files $uri $uri/ /loc2/index.php?$args; ... }` produces: ` *173 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/loc2/index.php", client: 127.0.0.1, server: www.server.dev, request: "GET /loc2/18ayBMOLVy HTTP/1.1", host: "www.server.dev" ` –